# Using React Hooks to Show Component Render Time and Date

Tags: react-hooks

My application contains a view that is a functional react component. I'm trying to add a timestamp at the bottom of the view displaying the date and time when the user navigated to this view. I'm wondering what would be appropriate way to implement this using hooks. I guess one option would be to use `const [date] = useState(new Date())` and simply provide no setter for the state since it would never change. However, this makes me wonder if `useState` is the appropriate hook to begin with. Should I just do `const date = new Date()` in the component body or would that have some unexpected side effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you intend to accomplish, the code below would work just fine:

```js
// solution # 1
function MyComponent() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div>
      View created at {time.toLocaleTimeString()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, it is important to know that it is not following React rules. That is because we are calling `new Date()` from inside the component, making it impure. React expects the components to be pure functions. This means that it should return the same thing for the same input. But React cannot guarantee that a function component doesn't have side effects, and that is why that first solution would work just fine.

According to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/75f0838967cd003cd7f9ab938eb1958f), a better approach for this task would be:

```js
// solution # 2
function MyComponent() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState<Date>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTime(new Date());
  }}, [])

  return (
    <div>
      View created at {time && time.toLocaleTimeString()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Roughly speaking, all side effects should live inside useEffect. So, things like calling an external API or calling impure functions (such as `Math.random()` or `Date.now()`) should be there. From my understanding, this solution would be more appropriate.

If we are not obeying React guidelines, the library might not work as advertised. Before version 18, React had only synchronous rendering. This means that the moment the render phase is kicked off (either by a initial render or by a state update), nothing could interrupt it from committing those updates to the browser. In that situation, I don't think the first solution I presented would be problematic. But, in React 18, we have the concurrent mode features by which rendering can be interrupted before the diffs are committed to the screen. With that, React can be more intelligent about how it breaks up all the work it needs to do (for example, we can now define high-priority updates).

In order for these new APIs to work properly, React assumes that the components are pure functions, which means that it has no side effects. These APIs are very new and there are still many more additional features coming in. I am not quite sure about how sensitive they are to function impurity, but I believe our second solution (with all side effects living inside the useEffect) is a better bet for this task.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work. Still not sure if this is optimal though.

```js
import  React from 'react'

export function View(_props) {

  const [viewCreated] = React.useState(Date.now())

  return (
    <div>
      View created {String(new Date(viewCreated))}
    </div>
  )

}
```

Answer (score -1):

useState(new Date()) is better. Here is complete component

```
import  React, { useState , useEffect } from 'react'
```

export const DateTime = () => {

```
var [date,setDate] = useState(new Date());

useEffect(() => {
    var timer = setInterval(()=>setDate(new Date()), 1000 )
    return function cleanup() {
        clearInterval(timer)
    }

});

return(
    <div>
        <p> Time : {date.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
        <p> Date : {date.toLocaleDateString()}</p>

    </div>
)
```

}

export default DateTime

Comment: Your example updates the time every second. My question was not about current time but the original render time of the component.

Comment: pass a empty array as sencod argument in the useEffect function useEffect(() => {}, []) like this. then it will be executed only when component mount.